# RubyのDouble SplatとRubyの他の機能との違いについて

Tags: ruby

[Drat! - Ruby has a Double Splat - Firmafon Developers Blog](https://dev.firmafon.dk/blog/drat-ruby-has-a-double-splat/)

を見ました。

### 質問1. 仮引数の** と = {} の違いはなんでしょうか？

```
def f(**options)
  p options #=> {:hoge=>"AAA", :foo=>"BBB"}
end

f hoge: "AAA", foo: "BBB"
```

と

```
def f(options = {})
  p options #=> {:hoge=>"AAA", :foo=>"BBB"}
end

f hoge: "AAA", foo: "BBB"
```

の違いはなんでしょうか？

### 実際に試してみた例

```
def f(options = {})
  p options #=> nil
end

f nil
```

> （とくに問題なし）

**エラー**

```
def f(**options)
  p options
end

f nil
```

> `f': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)

基準はわかりませんが、実引数に与えられた種類に応じてエラーにしてくれる場合が増えたということでしょうか？

### 質問2. ** と mergeメソッドとの違いは？

```
options = { a: 'b' }
hoge = { c: 'd', **options }
p hoge #=> {:c=>"d", :a=>"b"}

fuga =  { c: 'd'}.merge(options)
p fuga #=> {:c=>"d", :a=>"b"}
```

同じでしょうか？

Answer (score 3):

> 質問2. ** と mergeメソッドとの違いは？

ハッシュリテラルでは違いが分かりませんので、変数にします。

**{ **Hash, **Hash } の場合**

```
irb> h1 = { a: 'b'}
=> {:a=>"b"}
irb> h2 = { c: 'd'}
=> {:c=>"d"}
irb> h12 = { **h1, **h2 }
=> {:a=>"b", :c=>"d"}
irb> h1
=> {:a=>"b", :c=>"d"}
irb> h2
=> {:c=>"d"}
```

**merge メソッドの場合**

```
irb> h1 = { a: 'b'}
=> {:a=>"b"}
irb> h2 = { c: 'd'}
=> {:c=>"d"}
irb> h12 = h1.merge(h2)
=> {:a=>"b", :c=>"d"}
irb> h1
=> {:a=>"b"}
irb> h2
=> {:c=>"d"}
```

`{ **Hash, **Hash }` の場合は `h1` が書き変えられています。これは `Hash.merge!()` と同じです。

```
irb> h12 = h1.merge!(h2)
=> {:a=>"b", :c=>"d"}
irb> h1
=> {:a=>"b", :c=>"d"}
irb> h2
=> {:c=>"d"}
```

ソースコードでは以下の様になっていて、`Hash.merge()` の場合はコピーを渡している事が判るかと思います。

**ruby-2.6/hash.c**

```c
/*
 *  call-seq:
 *     hsh.merge(other_hash)
            :
*/
static VALUE
rb_hash_merge(VALUE hash1, VALUE hash2)
{
    return rb_hash_update(rb_obj_dup(hash1), hash2);
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}

/*
 *  call-seq:
 *     hsh.merge!(other_hash)
            :
 */
static VALUE
rb_hash_update(VALUE hash1, VALUE hash2)
{
    rb_hash_modify(hash1);
            :
```